# Replacing NaN Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes. I want to replace the missing values of a column in the first dataframe with a value that is in a column of the second dataframe. The 2 dataframes are like this:

First DataFrame:

```
Item_Identifier    Item_Weight    Item_Fat_Content    Item_Visibility    Item_Type
FDA15              9.0            Low Fat             0.016              Dairy
DRC01              NaN            Regular             0.017              Soft Drinks
```

Second DataFrame:

```
Item_Type     mean
Soft Drinks   8.7
Dairy         9.7
```

The NaN value in the first DataFrame should be replaced with 8.7. This is because the Item_Type is Soft Drinks, and in the second DataFrame the mean of Soft Drinks is 8.7.

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(big_mart)):
if pd.isna(big_mart.iloc[i, 1]) == True:
    for j in range(len(item_type_mean)):
        if big_mart.iloc[i, 4] == item_type_mean.iloc[j, 0]:
            big_mart.iloc[i, 1] == item_type_mean.iloc[j, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -

```
df1['Item_Weight'] = df1['Item_Weight'].fillna(df1['Item_Type'].map(df2.set_index('Item_Type')['mean']))
```

**Output**

```
  Item_Identifier  Item_Weight Item_Fat_Content  Item_Visibility    Item_Type
0           FDA15          9.0          Low_Fat            0.016        Dairy
1           DRC01          8.7          Regular            0.017  Soft_Drinks
```

Comment: Elegant. Thank a lot!!